# Implementation of classmethod

Tags: python, python-decorators, class-method

From the python documentation, the classmethod is roughly equivalent to

```
class ClassMethod(object):
    "Emulate PyClassMethod_Type() in Objects/funcobject.c"

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __get__(self, obj, klass=None):
        print(klass)
        if klass is None:
            klass = type(obj)
        def newfunc(*args):
            return self.f(klass, *args)
        return newfunc
```

My question is: In what cases, the klass is None.

I tested with a Test class

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @ClassMethod
    def fromstring(cls, s):
        res = cls()
        res.s = s
        return res

t1 = Test.fromstring("a")
t2 = Test()
t3 = t2.fromstring("a")
```

In those cases, the klass is <class '**main**.Test'>.

Comment: As a class method, `t2.fromstring` is the same thing as `Test.fromstring`, so I'm not sure what you're trying to show with that

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__):

> [PEP 252](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0252) specifies that [`__get__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__) is callable with one or two arguments. Python’s own built-in descriptors support this specification; however, it is likely that some third-party tools have descriptors that require both arguments. Python’s own [`__getattribute__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) implementation always passes in both arguments whether they are required or not.

`__get__` is specified to be callable with one argument, as the second argument is redundant when the first argument is non-`None`. However, `object.__getattribute__` and `type.__getattribute__` will never call `__get__` with a single argument.

Single-argument `__get__` calls would have to originate somewhere else - some code other than `object.__getattribute__` or `type.__getattribute__` calling `__get__` manually.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the question why there is a need for these two lines:

```
if klass is None:
    klass = type(obj)
```

It is true that when calling either `Test.fromstring("a")` or `t2.fromstring("a")`, the *klass* argument is filled in automatically as in always present.

However, the `__get()__` method can be also called directly by the user (or some other tool) with only the *obj* argument.  The classmethod will still work:

```
>>> vars(Test)['fromstring'].__get__(t2)("a").s
None
'a'
```